# VBA Odd Numbers/Mod

Tags: vba, modulo

I'm looking for some help with my VBA script. I'm stuck on trying to figure out how to use the mod function.

This is what I've done so far:

```
Function AddOddNumbersWithMod(nr)
    Dim i, sum
    sum = 0
    For i = (IF 1 MOD 2 = 0) to nr step 1
        sum = sum + i <-- (calculate all the odd numbers before nr)
    Next i
End Function
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please learn to format your code when posting here. You can find out how by clicking the *?* button at the top right of the area where you're typing your post. (And you have an obvious error in your code - look at the condition in the () after `For i =` and see if you can spot it.)

Comment: Why use a loop at all? `1 + 3 + 5 + ... + (2k-1) = k^2`.

Comment: learn loops https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_looping.asp

Comment: yet another way... `For i = 1 to nr step 2`

Comment: `If (1 Mod 2) = 0 ` will always be `False` or `0`. Why would you put a calculation in an `If` statement using nothing but fixed, magic numbers, that will always evaluate to the same answer? Just use `For i = 0 to nr` and find some other, _useful_ place to learn how to use `MOD`.

Comment: Rolled back - question was removed and replaced with just __This is what I've done so far:__

Answer (score 8):

For completeness sake, here is a loop-free version:

```
Function SumOfOdds(n As Long) As Long
    'returns sum 1 + 3 + 5 + ... of all odd numbers <= n
    SumOfOdds = Int((n + 1) / 2) ^ 2
End Function
```

Based on this picture:

[image]

The L-like shapes contain successive odd numbers and nicely fit together to form perfect squares. This nice pattern was well-known to the ancient Greeks.

Comment: I was trying to work out the equation, that truly is a thing of beauty :)

Comment: Very instructive, hats off.

Comment: Poetry of a Math Teacher :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Function AddOddNumbersWithMod(nr)
    Dim i As Long, sum As Long
    sum = 0
    For i = 1 To nr - 1 Step 1
        If (i Mod 2 <> 0) Then
            sum = sum + i  ' <-- (calculate all the odd numbers before nr)
        End If
    Next i

    AddOddNumbersWithMod = sum
End Function
```

To add odd numbers without Mod, you can use Step 2 to skip even numbers starting from 1.

```
Function AddOddNumbersWithoutMod(nr)
    Dim i As Long, sum As Long
    sum = 0
    For i = 1 To nr - 1 Step 2
        sum = sum + i  ' <-- (calculate all the odd numbers before nr)
    Next i

    AddOddNumbersWithoutMod = sum
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the result of i Mod 2 to be 1, it shows the remainder and if you are using 2 as your divisor you want a remainder of 1 to show an odd number. For example 7 mod 2 = 1, this is because 7 divided by 2 equals 3 with a remainder of 1, it's that remainder that we are interested in.:

```
Function AddOddNumbersWithMod(nr)
    Dim i As Double, MySum As Double
    For i = 0 To nr
         If i Mod 2 = 1 Then MySum = MySum + i ' <-- (calculate all the odd numbers before nr)
    Next i
    AddOddNumbersWithMod = MySum
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Oddeven()
  Dim x As Double
  x = InputBox("Please enter the Number: ")
  If x Mod 2 = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("The Number is the Even Number")
  Else
    MsgBox ("The Number is the Odd Number")
  End If
End Sub
```